# is there a performSelector on some boolean in ios development

Tags: ios, xcode, core-location, performselector

I'm using CoreLocation,and I want to call a method to do some computations on the latitude and longitude after they have been assigned valid values or after these values have been updated.

How do you implement this? I was considering using performSelector, but those methods take a time delay -- i don't want a time delay, i want to know that latitude and longitude have valid values first.

Comment: Any reason why you want to use performSelector? You can just do the work in CoreLocation delegate methods.

Comment: The time delay can be 0 for performSelector methods.  Could you use KVO if you don't want to use performSelector?

Comment: No.  `-performSelector:` gives you no assurance whatsoever that a lat/long will be valid at the time of the call, a *classic* race condition.  As indicated by @sosborn, and fleshed out by @ElJay below, the correct approach is using the delegate callbacks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not call whatever method you want in Core Locations delegate method:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation;
```

Rule of thumb is to ignore the first set of CLLocation coordinates.

Comment: It should also be noted that `CLLocation` has `horizontalAccuracy` and `verticalAccuracy` properties that can be useful in deciding whether to ignore/discard a location update.